# How to set multiple model values to javascript button id

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

Here i have button with id "edit%@SL.PackageID%@SL.RefServiceID" in this  iam getting both packageid and refserviceid values but i am unable to concatenate that both values to button id.

This is button code:

```
<button class="btn btn-default disableedit" id="edit%@SL.PackageID%@SL.RefServiceID" onclick="EditServices(this.id.split('%')[1])" type="button" name="Edit" title="Edit" disabled="disabled"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o bookap_icon"></i></button>
```

And this is my function:

```
function EditServices(PackageID, RefServiceID) {               
            window.location.href = "@Url.Action("EditServicesToProvider", "ServiceProvider")?PackageID=" + PackageID + "&RefServiceID=" + RefServiceID;          
        }
```

Here i am getting PackageID but not RefServiceID in alert iam getting "undefined". But i want value it is coming in model.

Comment: This code is just bad. First, that's not a valid HTML id. You should be using `data-*` attributes instead. Second, there's no reason to join these and then try to parse them back out. Just do something like `data-packageId="@SL.PackageID" data-refServiceId="@SL.RefServiceID"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you split the id, it breaks into 3 subparts, "Edit", "PackageID" and  "RefServiceID".

To send the later two as parameters , modify `onclick` as

```
onclick="EditServices(this.id.split('%')[1], this.id.split('%')[2])"
```